Issues with Environment Variable Initialization in Next.js 15
I just created a new project using Next.js 15. In my previous version, I used next/env in a certain way as per there official documentation, and I tried using the same approach in this new version, but it’s not working. Could someone please help me figure out the correct way to initialize environment variables in Next.js 15? Is there a new method for doing this?
What I tried: I initialized environment variables in my Next.js 15 project using the next/env package, similar to how I did in previous versions (like Next.js 14).
What I expected: I expected the environment variables to be loaded correctly and accessible via process.env in both server-side and client-side code, just like in previous versions of Next.js.
What actually happened: The environment variables were not loaded properly, and process.env returned undefined for all variables. This made the application unable to access critical configuration settings like API URLs.

You don't need the next/env package in Next.js v15. It loads your env files automatically.
To know how to use environment variables in Next 15, you can check my article on using environment variables in next js, which describes the correct way to set up environment files and variables, and all the possible things that could go wrong including reasons why your variables could be undefined.
Some of the possible culprits are:

not adding NEXT_PUBLIC_ in front of the variable when you need it in the client-side code
not restarting your next server after adding the variables
putting your env file in the wrong place
not adding your variables in the dashboard when building on hosting platforms like Vercel or Netlify

